# How to rewrite a SQL query in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I'm trying to rewrite a SQL query in LINQ to Entities. I'm using LINQPad with a typed datacontext from my own assembly to test things out.

The SQL query I'm trying to rewrite:

```
SELECT DISTINCT variantID AS setID, option_value AS name, option_value_description AS description, sort_order as sortOrder
FROM all_products_option_names AS lst
WHERE lst.optionID=14 AND lst.productID IN (SELECT productID FROM all_products_option_names
                                            WHERE optionID=7 AND option_value IN (SELECT name FROM brands
                                                                                  WHERE brandID=1))
ORDER BY sortOrder;
```

The LINQ to Entities query I've come up with so far (which doesn't work due to a timeout error):

```
from a in all_products_option_names
where a.optionID == 14 && all_products_option_names.Any(x => x.productID == a.productID && x.optionID == 7 && brands.Any(y => y.name == x.option_value && y.brandID == 1))
select new
{
    id = a.variantID,
    name = a.option_value,
    description = a.option_value_description,
    sortOrder = a.sort_order,
}
```

This is the error I get when I run the above query: `An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.`

And the inner exception is: `Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

**Edit:**

I use MySQL and probably that's why LINQPad doesn't show me the generated SQL.

The SQL version doesn't time out.

**Edit 2:**

I solved the problem by completely changing the query, so this question is irrelevant now.

I marked Steven's response as the correct one, because he was closest to what i was trying to achieve and his response gave me the idea which led me to the solution.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: Does the SQL version of the query time out as well?

Comment: Are you using the latest IQ Drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var brandNames =
    from brand in db.Brands
    where brand.ID == 1
    select name;

var brandProductNames =
    from p in db.all_products_option_names
    where p.optionID == 7
    where brandNames.Contains(p.option_value)
    select p.productId;

var results =
    from p in db.all_products_option_names
    where p.optionID == 14
    where brandProductNames.Contains(p.productId)
    select new
    {
        setID = p.variantID, 
        name = p.option_value, 
        description = p.option_value_description, 
        sortOrder = p.sort_order
    };
```

Comment: I like the idea of splitting the query, but this still gives the same timeout error.

Comment: Does every query time out? If not, use the SQL profiler and index tuning wizard to tune the query. Perhaps you're missing some indexes.

Comment: Only the last query times out.

Comment: LINQ queries are deferred. Those three statements (as shown in my code) do nothing by themselves. Only if you start iterating an `IQueryable` (or calling `ToArray`, `Count`, `Any`, etc) will a SQL query be sent to the database. You should start using a SQL Profiler to see this in action.

Comment: I know that LINQ queries are deferred. But i called the `Dump()` method from LINQPad for each of them and i see the results for the first two and the last one times out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing joins rather than sub-select's as you have them. Sub-selects are not very efficient when you look at performance, it's like having loops inside of loops when you code , not a good idea. This could actually cause that timeout your getting if your database is running slowly even thou that looks like a simple query.

Comment: I'm going to try that. On the other hand, this is not production code, it's code used to do an import from an old web store using a MySQL db.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you're querying a database. Your query is translated to SQL and it's up to the SQL Server as to whether it internaly uses nested loops or hash joins or whatever.

Comment: Ofcoarse it matters Joe when you use joins the database doesn't have to do full table scans and can rely strongly on indexed keys unlike nested selects who can be very detrimental to performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `joins` with a `distinct` at the end like this:

```
var results =
    (from p in db.all_products_option_names
     join p2 in db.all_products_option_names on p.productId equals p2.productId
     join b in db.Brands on p2.option_value equals b.name
     where p.optionID == 14
     where p2.optionID == 7
     where b.BrandID == 1
     select new
     {
        setID = p.variantID, 
        name = p.option_value, 
        description = p.option_value_description, 
        sortOrder = p.sort_order
     }).Distinct();
```

Or you could try using `joins` with the `into` and with an `any` like so

```
 var results =
         from p in db.all_products_option_names
         join p2 in (from p3 in db.all_products_option_names.Where(x => x.optionId == 7) 
                     join b in db.Brands.Where(x => x.BrandID == 1) on p3.option_value equals b.name 
                     select p3) into pg
         where p.optionID == 14
         where pg.Any()
         select new
         {
            setID = p.variantID, 
            name = p.option_value, 
            description = p.option_value_description, 
            sortOrder = p.sort_order
         };
```

Comment: The first method has 0 items in the result (so something is not right).

Comment: The second method gives the following error in LINQPad: `The name 'p2' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.`

Comment: @david.s - I fixed the second one. Without seeing some sample data, I wouldn't be able to see what the result should be